# Can i wear shri ram locket?

Tags: ramayana, rama, hanuman, ramakrishna

Can i wear shri ram locket? Do i need to remove it while going to washroom? I haven't bought it yet but thinking about it but this thought was again and agaun coming to my mind. So kindly suggest.